# IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

Tags: python, list, indexoutofboundsexception

So this is my code to plot a Bézier curve:

```
def bezier(a):
    n = np.shape(a)[0]-1
        # initialise arrays
    B = np.zeros([101, 2])
    terms = np.zeros([n+1, 2])
        # create an array of values for t from 0 to 1 in 101 steps
    t = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)
        # loop through all t values
    for i in range(0, 101):
            #calculate terms inside sum in equation 13
            for j in range(0, n + 1):
                # YOUR CODE HERE
                terms[j,:] = ((1 - t[i]) ** 3 * a[0,:] \
                           + 3 * t[i] * (1-t[i]) ** 2 * a[1,:] \
                           + 3 * t[i] ** 2 * (1-t[i]) * a[2,:] 
                           + t[i] ** 3 * a[3,:])
        #sum terms to find Bezier curve
    B[i, :] = sum(terms, 0)
        # plot Bezier
    pl.plot(B[:, 0], B[:, 1])
        # plot control points
    pl.plot(a[:, 0], a[:, 1],'ko')
        # plot control polygon
    pl.plot(a[:, 0], a[:, 1],'k')
    return B
```

And when I try to pass it some control points:

```
a = np.array([[0, 0], [0.5, 1], [1, 0]])
B = bezier(a)
```

I receive this IndexError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-fce87c9f1c04> in <module>()
      1 a = np.array([[0, 0], [0.5, 1], [1, 0]])
----> 2 B = bezier(a)

<ipython-input-13-3bb3bb02cc87> in bezier(a)
     11            for j in range(0, n + 1):
     12                # YOUR CODE HERE
---> 13                terms[j,:] = ((1 - t[i]) ** 3 * a[0,:] + 3 * t[i] * (1-t[i]) ** 2 * a[1,:] + 3 * t[i] ** 2 * (1-t[i]) * a[2,:] + t[i] ** 3 * a[3,:])
     14        #sum terms to find Bezier curve
     15    B[i, :] = sum(terms, 0)

IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

So I figure it is trying to access something outside the container but I can't see where it is I need to change the code.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36489042/5320906)?

Answer (score 1):

You array `a = np.array([[0, 0], [0.5, 1], [1, 0]]` does not have element with index 3. Add another point to the array. You need four points for a Bezier curve, anyway.